# Is it possible to call SignHash and VerifyHash with RsaCryptoServiceProvider without the expensive OID lookup?

Tags: c#, performance, rsa, digital-signature

I need to sign and verify around a hundred messages / sec using RSA (Key size 1024 bit).

For signing the message I am calculating the hash of the data using SHA2 and then passing the hash to SignHash.

```
rsaCryptoServiceProvider.SignHash(hashOfData, "SHA2");
```

To verify the signature I use

```
rsaCryptoServiceProvider.VerifyHash(hashOfData, "SHA2", signature);
```

Calling these methods with null throws an exception. Similarly, using

```
CryptoConfig.MapNameToOid("SHA2")
```

also contacts the domain controller and takes a lot of time.

I have tried the same with SHA1 and MD5 too. Is there any way I can skip the OID lookup for both SignHash and VerifyHash?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that passing null as the second parameter forces the use of SHA1. Using any other algorithm requires a Oid lookup.